# openCV (the function is not implemented)

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

Trying to run a python script and it throws the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file /root/mc-x64-2.7/conda-bld/opencv-3_1482255590695/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 527
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C1_DrawBboxesOnImages.py", line 90, in <module>
    cv2.namedWindow("AnnotationWindow")
cv2.error: /root/mc-x64-2.7/conda-bld/opencv-3_1482255590695/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:527: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvNamedWindow
```

I have installed the libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config but still get the same error.please any one can help me.

Answer (score 0):

**then re-run cmake or configure script**

The library wasn't built with this feature, if you built the lib yourself you need to rebuild as it says. If you downloaded it as a package you need to find a version with gtk support built in

Comment: You may need to delete the cmake cache so it picks up the new lib